# Chrome issue with Print Preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like when clicking a button to print preview the page. So far I have the following code:

```
  print(resultId){
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'height=800,width=1240');
    printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    // printWindow.print();
    // printWindow.close();
    // return true;
  }
```

This will open a new window but it does not open print preview, so basically you have to click ctrl+p and then click print button in Print Preview.

If I uncomment the commented code above then it opens directly Print Preview but the page is blank on Chrome. Any idea why this is happening? How do I fix this?

UPDATE (tried this way also still blank):

```
  print(resultId){
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', "width="+screen.availWidth+", height="+screen.availHeight);
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
    printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">');
    printWindow.document.write('</head>');
    printWindow.document.write('<body>');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
    return true;
  }
```

UPDATE 2:

```
 print(resultId){{ 
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', "width="+screen.availWidth+", height="+screen.availHeight);
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
    // printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">');
    printWindow.document.write('</head>');
    printWindow.document.write('<body>');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
    return true;
  }
```

This will open Print Priview fine on Chrome but ofc without styling.

Comment: what result do you get in other browsers?

Comment: @ADyson for example in Firefox I get the print preview with all content (html,css) working all good, but in Chrome it shows a blank Print Preview.

Comment: I don't know if it's definitely the issue, but document.write is a very out of date way to do things...try creating the new window with proper HTML and body tags, and then set the innerHTML of the body element in the new window to the desired content. Maybe Chrome is unhappy with your rather basic document structure or something. Either way it would be a more up to date way to code it anyway

Comment: @ADyson already created it with proper tags like html, head, body I still get the same result, blank page! thou strangely it works all fine in Chrome if I uncomment the commented code and add the styling as inline style <style>body{background: red}</style>. but this way I am ending up with duplicate css. When trying to use  printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">'); then it shows blank.

Comment: Create your html with html,head and body tags. However I suggest you to use a printing js library

Comment: That suggests maybe the link is not working then? I think you can open the dev tools for the popup and check that. Another potential option of course is just to ditch the separate window and set your existing page up for printing using CSS media queries to set print-appropriate styles for the content.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos why do we need a printing JS library, in your opinion? It should be possible to achieve this with regular HTML and CSS, nothing complicated is taking place.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos check my question the UPDATE section, still bank showing

Comment: @ADyson link is working when I try to open it on the browser its full url, console shows nothing. I dont know about this dev tool why do u mean?

Comment: if you're already looking at the console then you're already using developer tools - the console is one part of those tools. What I mean is to open the console for the popup window specifically, then see if it successfully loaded the CSS file into the window or not.

Comment: @ADyson i Updated my question, pls check the last section. Also still I cannot see on the console anything on the Printe Privew console

Comment: @ADyson, I now can see this msg on console for Print Preview in Chrome: [Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML Imports is deprecated. Please refer to goo.gl/EGXzpw for possible migration paths. I get deprecated msg even when I remove printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">')

Comment: it says to copy <style is="custom-style"> to the main document, but in my case i dont know what is main document, should I added it inside the alternativePrint function?